# Divide row 1 value by row 2 value and place it in row 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I’m in middle of a task where I want to divide row 1 revenue by row 2 revenue and place it in row 3. How can this be accomplished? Note that row 3 is not present and should be constructed using the query.

Data set:

```
Name Date Quarter Type Revenue
A1 2018-12-31 4q2018 x1 5000
A1 2018-12-31 4q2018 x2 2000
A1 2018-12-31 4q2018 xdiv 2.5 (expected output)
A1 2018-09-30 3q2018 x1 5000
A1 2018-09-30 3q2018 x2 1000
A1 2018-09-30 3q2018 xdiv 5 (expected output)
B1 2018-12-31 4q2018 x1 5000
B1 2018-12-31 4q2018 x2 5000
B1 2018-12-31 4q2018 xdiv 1 (expected output)
B1 2018-09-30 3q2018 x1 10000
B1 2018-09-30 3q2018 x2 1000
B1 2018-09-30 3q2018 xdiv 10 (expected output)
```

Comment: Need more clarifications.

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: This isn't something SQL Server can do. For a start you're going to be mixing data types in the Revenue column. You should look at building this into a report or creating a separate table for the calculated row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL` for this.

The first query simply selects the x1 & x2
The second unioned query adds the xdiv
The `ORDER BY` at the end sorts the result of the union.

```
SELECT [Name], [Date], [Quarter], [Type], CAST(Revenue AS FLOAT) AS Revenue
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Type] IN ('x1','x2')

UNION ALL

SELECT x1.[Name], x1.[Date], x1.[Quarter], 'xdiv', (x1.Revenue * 1.0 / NULLIF(x2.Revenue,0))
FROM YourTable x1
JOIN YourTable x2 ON (x2.[Name] = x1.[Name] AND x2.[Date] = x1.[Date] AND x2.[Type] = 'x2')
WHERE x1.[Type] = 'x1'

ORDER BY [Name], [Date] DESC, [Type]
```

The `NULLIF` was added to avoid a "Divide by zero" error.

Comment: xDiv records should be constructed using the query. So, update statement won’t work

Comment: Wait a moment. I can also add an INSERT to add the missing xdiv. But are you actually looking for something to correct a table, or just a query that also has the xdiv?

Comment: I’m looking for a query with additional records. In the above dataset, 8 records are already present and I’ve to insert 4 more records of xDiv type.

Comment: @Madhukar Thanks. A side-note.  If your intention is to [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) the x1 & x2 revenues, then adding those xdiv in the source query wouldn't be needed.  Because with a PIVOT you could just calculate the xdiv directly from the privoted x1 & x2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
 UPDATE R3 SET R3.VALUE=(R1.VALUE/R2.VALUE) FROM Table1 R3 
    LEFT JOIN  Table1 R1 ON R1.id = 1  
    LEFT JOIN Table1 R2 ON R2.ID = 2
    WHERE R3.id=3
```